Firebase signin with Linkedin through OIDC
I try to sign in user through LinkedIn. Since Firebase does not have direct support for LinkedIn, I config OIDC provider
On the LinkedIn app side, I have configured the redirect URI to Firebase app: https://-7e81a.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
On the Firebase side, I have added new OIDC provider,add client id and secret id, set issuer URL to: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth
When I test signing in with JS:
  console.log("Sign in with LinkedIn");
  const provider = new OAuthProvider("oidc.linkedin");
  const auth = getAuth();
  await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  console.log("Sign in with LinkedIn done");

The sign in window pops up correctly, I can also login LinkedIn account, but when I press the authorize button, It reports the following errors

A HTTP post request to https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=xxx returns 400 error
The Firebase js SDK reports:

firebase_auth.js?v=ffaae778:672 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error getting access token from https://www.linkedin.com/oauth,

I suspect this is a config error, but have no clue how to debug it. Any idea?

This is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78563229
You need to go into the Products section of your app and enable "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect"

It’s obviously not related to that as OP was prompted to authenticate which wouldn’t happen unless they have configured their app correctly.  There’s another issues with firebase auth and LinkedIn oidc connections that the firebase team are working to resolve.
